# Is there a way to save a filter in Trello?

Tags: trello

I like to view our board filtered by cards assigned to me with the rest hidden. Every time I go to Trello, to get this view, I have to click filter, choose me, and switch from translucent to hidden.

Is there a way to save this filter so that every time I go to Trello the board has this filter applied already?

Comment: Hi there, times are changing and you need to accept the new answer by @samthebrand

Comment: Hi there, I don't *need* to do anything, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to save card filters, though it's something that has been considered and may be implemented in the future.

To quickly filter just your cards, you can use the 'q' shortcut. Just hit 'q' while viewing a board.

Comment: (I work on the Trello team.)

Comment: Thanks! I really should look into the keyboard shortcuts....

Comment: Check out https://trello.com/shortcuts !

Comment: Is it still true that you cannot share or permalink a filtered view of a Trello board?

Comment: The new shortcuts have an `F` shortcut to show the menu for all available filters by label

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is now possible.

Filtered view URLs can be accessed by filtering a board, and accessing the updated URL (or clicking the green "Filtering is on" button).

[image: Filtered view of a Trello board]

Copy the updated URL and share it or bookmark it to access a filtered view of the board. The URL looks like this:

`https://trello.com/b/4Y0idQQT/kitchen-project?menu=filter&filter=label:yellow`

Answer (score 0):

From the trello board:
"I just had a really good idea for Trello! Where can I submit it?"

Check the Trello Development board. We may already be working on it. Can't find it?

Email your idea to feature-ideas@trello.com.

The trello developmet board is at:
 https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c

or google trello development