# Is there a way to save a filter on Trello (2015 edition)?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, trello-labels

I've found a couple of related questions on this but the most recent is from 2012.

I'm trying to save a link to a filtered view of my Trello board. Is this possible? Specifically, I'd like to save a link to all cards with a particular label.

I found a couple of older cards, including this one from late 2011 in which a Trello employee says that Trello is considering the feature, but I can't find an update on it:
[Is there a way to save a filter in Trello?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22238/is-there-a-way-to-save-a-filter-in-trello)

Comment: [Bobby Grace](http://stackexchange.com/users/306274/bobby-grace) are you able to help with this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Trello Gold, one workaround is to save a search with your specific criteria.

To find all of X label on Y board:

`label:label-name board:board-name`

Then click "Save this search" in the search box. It's cludgy but it works. There might be a plugin/extension to do what you're wanting as well.

Comment: Also:

`https://trello.com/search?q=`